# Calculating limits of integrals of volume

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a few problems to do with finding the volume under surfaces. The first ones were fairly simple:
$$h(x,y)=xy^2\,,0\le x\le1\,,1\le y\le2$$
$$\therefore V=\int_1^2\int_0^1\int_0^{xy^2}dzdxdy=\int_1^2\int_0^1xy^2dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2y^2dy=\frac{7}{6}$$

However, on later questions the boundaries are given as:
$$h(x,y)=e^{-x-y}\,,0\le x\,,y<\infty$$
which to me implies:
$$V=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\exp(-x-y)}dzdxdy.$$
However this evaluates to:
$$V=\left[e^y\right]_{-\infty}^\infty.$$
which is clearly divergent.

How should I calculate what the limits are for this volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundaries $0\leq x,y < \infty$ mean that both $x$ and $y$ can have non-negative values:
$$
 \begin{align*}
  0 \leq x < \infty \\
  0 \leq y < \infty.
 \end{align*}
$$
So the lower bound in the outer integral (integrating w.r.t $y$) should be $0$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense now